# I am getting an error "Argument not specified for parameter 'Judges' of 'Public Property Scores(Judges As Integer) As Integer'."

Tags: vb.net

This is my property method

```
Public Property Scores(ByVal Judges As Integer) As Integer

    Get
        Return _Scores(Judges)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _Scores(Judges) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I call It in the constructor to resize the array

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal ID As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Judges As Integer, ByVal Grade As Integer)
    _ID = ID
    Me.Name = Name
    Me.Judges = Judges
    Me.Grade = Grade
    ReDim Scores(Judges)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `ReDim` a property? `ReDim` requires an array. Need more info.

Comment: I am using ReDim in my constructor

Comment: Perhaps what you meant to code is `ReDim _Scores(Judges)`.

Comment: It appears your property is returning an integer not an array value. see MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sd8c1d6(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I wouldn't use *Judges* as a parameter name. It implies either a count or collection. Being an Integer, wouldn't *numberOfJudges* be a better name? The implication is that it causes confusion, as demonstrated in this question and its comments.

Comment: I'm wondering how you expect to ReDim a property which is an Integer, `Scores(ByVal Judges As Integer) As Integer`. Please see what ReDim does:  [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)